# What is a two way header list?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

i couldn't find any clear and precise information on google regarding this.
So please help.
This is a subtopic in **LINKED LIST-DATA STRUCTURES** in my college course.

Comment: Is it not just a synonym for "doubly-linked list"? What does your textbook have to say about it; as it is not a common term.

Comment: @Botje i am not following any text book, just checking the syllabus and studying directly from google. this topic i came across studying linked list and is seperate from doubly linked list in syllabus.   my teacher is 1 unit behind , so i ain't asking him for now.

Comment: It is not standard terminology, so unless you can point us to what your syllabus thinks it is, we cannot help you.

Comment: @Botje thanks, i think i will skip this topic for now

Comment: It might be reference to a doubly linked list with header node for each end; or the header node has pointer to both first and last node; Purely guessing though